# Qt/C++ динамическая надпись на 3D текстуре куба

Tags: c++, qt, 3d

Пробую работать с Qt 3D C++ и понадобилось выводить динамически созданную надпись на текстуру куба. Код для отрисовки куба:

```
    Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh *cuboid = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh(cuboidEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QTransform *cuboidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(cuboidEntity);
    cuboidTransform->setScale(15.0f);
    cuboidTransform->setTranslation( QVector3D ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *cuboidMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(cuboidEntity);
    cuboidMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0x007fff)));       

    cuboidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(m_rootEntity);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboid);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidMaterial);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(cuboidTransform);
```

Каким образом можно добавить на текстуры куба надпись "123"?

Comment: Готового метода я так и не нашёл. Поэтому через QPainter создал изображение, сохранил его и наложил на куб